# django- createview, get id with which it was saved in database return "None", self.object.pk in form_valid is "None"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have created a view with createview where I have a form, this view has the url:  `path('asignacionContact/<int:pk>/',AsignacionCreateView.as_view(), name='assignacion_contact')` , I fill the form and effectively it is saved in the database, but I want to get the id with which it was saved in the database, so in the form_valid method I try to get the id with `self.object.pk` or `form.instance.pk`  but it returns None , how can I fix this?

```
urls.py

app_name = 'gestionAsignacion'

urlpatterns = [
     
    path('asignacionContact/<int:pk>/',AsignacionCreateView.as_view(), name='asignacion_contact'),
    path('detalle/asignacion/<int:pk>',descargarAsignacion.as_view(), name='descargar_asignacion'),
    path('asignacionGeneral/',asignacionGeneral.as_view(), name='asignacion_general'),
    
    
]

model.py

class AsignacionContact(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    idasignacion_general = models.ForeignKey('AsignacionGeneral', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idasignacion_general')
    nombre_asignacion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    fecha_fin = models.DateField()
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    estado = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_asignacion
    
    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     print('reverse')
    #     return reverse('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_contact',kwargs={ 'pk': self.pk })

    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'asignacion_contact'

view.py

class AsignacionCreateView(CreateView):
    model=AsignacionContact
    form_class=AsignacionForm
    template_name='gestionAsignacion/asignacion_contact.html'
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_general')
    
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        
        isvalid = super().form_valid(form)
        print('form_valid')
        print(form.instance.pk)
        print(self.object.pk)
        return isvalid
        
    
   
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('post')
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AsignacionCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        print('hola succes')
        print(self.object.id)
        return reverse('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_general')
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) you can save and get the id of the save.

```
>>> b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
>>> b2.id     # Returns None, because b2 doesn't have an ID yet.
>>> b2.save()
>>> b2.id     # Returns the ID of your new object
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, although it was not the solution, it helped me to realize that my id field in the database is autoincremental but in the model.py I had it as "IntegerField", I made the change to AutoField and now I can get the id with "self.object.pk" in form_valid